# How to connect an existing database to SQL Server so that appears in SQL Server Objects Explorer

Tags: sql-server, database, reconnect

I have disconnected my db that was visible under the SQL Server Objects Explorer in order to move the database files to a proper folder and now I cannot find the way to reconnect it. I want it to show in the same window (SQL Server Objects Explorer in VS), where all other databases are visible.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: this could be it : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt710791.aspx

Comment: You have to "attach" your db files to some `SQL SERVER INSTANCE`

Comment: Check this: [StackExchange post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52007/how-do-i-move-sql-server-database-files)

Comment: I can reconnect it, but now the connection string is changed, it contains the whole path of the db and also in the sql server objects explorer appearsnow with the full path, not just with the name as before